# How to get par formatter to not mangle paragraphs with non-space character prefixes, suffixes?

Tags: vim, text-formatting, word-wrap

I can't get the [par formatter](http://www.nicemice.net/par/) to do what I want, specifically with automated prefixes and suffixes. Details:

My `.vimrc` excerpt:

```
set formatprg=par\ -w72reqh
map t gqip
```

This example input-to-[par](http://www.nicemice.net/par/) text that demonstrates the problem:

```
1. This is some text with similar sentence beginnings and endings.
   The snake slithered through the grass, sliding back and forth.
   Tactfully approaching its prey.
```

Applying my vim-par-formatting (pressing the `t` key in vim command mode) settings to the above results in:

```
1. This is some text with similar sentence beginnings and endings he   .
   Tsnake slithered through the grass, sliding back and forth actfully .
   Tapproaching its prey                                               .
```

Notice the left-side/prefix `T`'s and right-side/suffix periods are "justified." Obviously not what I want. I instead want the results (of pressing the `t` key in vim command mode) to look like this:

```
1. This is some text with similar sentence beginnings and endings. The
   snake slithered through the grass, sliding back and forth. Tactfully
   approaching its prey.
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6738514/605356) appears to simply disable [par](http://www.nicemice.net/par/) suffixes and prefixes and won't generate my preferred (above) result. I'm hopeful there's some way to get [par](http://www.nicemice.net/par/) to prefix only space characters, or some such?

The solution may involve breaking other [par](http://www.nicemice.net/par/) functionality, like "justifying" the C-code-comment characters in the example [found here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Par_text_reformatter). But I'm taking this one step at a time. Maybe I (eventually) employ 2 different par-formatting vim commands, one for space-delimited text like above, another for C-comment formatting, etc. For now, let's solve the above and then I'll investigate the next (C-comment, etc) steps as need be.

My environment:

```
$ par version
par 1.52-i18n.4
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.9.5
BuildVersion:   13F1077
$ brew list par
/usr/local/Cellar/par/1.52/bin/par
/usr/local/Cellar/par/1.52/share/man/man1/par.1.gz
$ which par
/usr/local/bin/par
$ vim --version | head -2
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Apr 21 2014 14:54:22)
MacOS X (unix) version
$
```

Comment: Does this question better suited to stackoverflow.com?